# size of icons in lockscreen and quick settings got larger after updating from 22.10 to 23.04

Tags: 23.04

[this is how my quick settings look right now][1]

dont know what to do on this
tried to see if this is a common problem and it is but the effects are different and everyone tried different methods

i tried to copy that but no result
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWhsT.png